# Passing a file to Security Essentials for scanning

Tags: delphi, ms-security-essentials

Does anyone have an idea on how to pass a file to Security Essentials (SE) for scanning?

When SE is installed it adds a line to the Explorer popup menu, "Scan with MS SE" and I'd like to be able to scan a specific file if SE has been installed on the host PC.

I can check for msseces.exe to see if it is installed but I can't find any command line information that will scan a specific file passed to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why closed? Looks perfectly valid problem. Ever seen Firefox attempts to scan a downloaded file with whaterver available A/V software?

Comment: Autocracy out of control. The guys that voted to Close did not think it through. When I said "file passed to it," how on earth did they think that would happen if it was not as a result of a programmed assignment "ShellExecEx(..." in my App? Needta look at the big picture and not just knee-jerk at the first thought guys. :)

Comment: this more like an oligarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at MPCMDRUN.EXE. Run it with /? to get all the options.

It sits in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client" on my current system.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already searched online and this info is all I could find... [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg131918.aspx) and nothing useful there.